Eclipse/WWD is folding Angular imports while I write them
I'm having an annoying problem with Angular imports on Eclipse/WWD. I'm using the lastest version of both Eclipse and WWD.
While I'm editing a change in a module's imports, the editor folds the imports during typing, forcing me to edit the line in another part of the text and recopying to the imports section.
I already disabled all "Folding" options I can find and the problem continues.
I've seen some answers in other posts advising to turn off folding for Java files, but as I'm using a PDT derived version there's no "Java" section.
Anyone knows how to solve this ?
Where is a video of the problem happening:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tcnme7ta5kQ
This is my Eclipse installation:

Edit
I've found issues/discussions related to this problem, but no solution:
https://github.com/eclipse-wildwebdeveloper/wildwebdeveloper/discussions/1517
https://github.com/eclipse/lsp4e/issues/895
